# biblatex: Switching languages for *citations* according to the bibentry's "hyphenation" field

Tags: biblatex, citing, languages, hyphenation, babel

Quoting from section 3.1.2.1 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf):

> [The `babel`] option controls which
>   language environment is used if the
>   `babel` package is loaded and a
>   bibliography entry includes a
>   hyphenation field [...]. Note that
>   `biblatex` automatically adjusts to
>   the main document language if `babel`
>   is loaded. In multilingual documents,
>   it will also continually adjust to the
>   current language as far as citations
>   and the default language of the
>   bibliography is concerned. This option
>   is for switching languages on a
>   per-entry basis within the
>   bibliography.

Suppose that, in a text with the  main language "ngerman", I cite a bibentry with the hyphenation field "english". By default, the *in-text-citation* will use the hyphenation pattern for *"ngerman"*. That is, if the citation style uses author names, titles or even full bibliographic data, hyphenation of these items is prone to be wrong. Case in point: The author William A. Fischel (an American) should be hyphenated "Fis-chel", but German hyphenation patterns will result in "Fi-schel".

My current workaround is to include any such author in TeX's hyphenation exception list, but this is clumsy and error-prone for longer texts. (Manually enclosing every citation in an appropriate `otherlanguage` environment is not an option for the same reasons.) My envisaged solution is to use the "hyphenation" field to automatically switch to the correct language *in-text* for every citekey. `biblatex` provides an `\AtEveryCitekey` hook (to be used only in the preamble), so this should be possible in principle. In the following example, I show that switching languages on a one-time basis is possible using `\AtNextCitekey`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Fis85,
  hyphenation = {english},
  author = {Fischel, William A.},
  year = {1985},
  title = {The economics of zoning laws: A property rights approach to American land use planning},
  location = {Baltimore},
  publisher = {Johns Hopkins University Press},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textwidth=290pt

% My current workaround: Include author names in the hyphenation exception list
% \hyphenation{Fis-chel}

% My envisaged solution: At every citekey, switch to the language defined in the bibentry's
%     "hyphenation" field. This doesn't work because babel strips away the escape character "\"
%     from "\thefield{hyphenation}"
% \AtEveryCitekey{\selectlanguage{\thefield{hyphenation}}}

\begin{document}

Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben \autocite{Fis85}.

% The following code line shows that my envisaged solution (see above) would work if
%     "\thefield{hyphenation}" would be expanded to (in this case) "english"
%     (Note: "\AtNextCitekey" is the "one-time" variant of  "\AtEveryCitekey"
\AtNextCitekey{\selectlanguage{english}}

Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben \autocite{Fis85}.

Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben \autocite{Fis85}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So why doesn't my envisaged solution work? Trying

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\selectlanguage{\thefield{hyphenation}}}
```

results in the the following error message:

> Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language thefield{hyphenation}

That is, instead of expanding `\thefield{hyphenation}` to "english" (as I naively assumed), `babel` strips away away the escape character `\` from `\thefield{hyphenation}` and then complains about an unknown language. (According to section 7 of the [`babel` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/babel/babel.pdf), this stripping away is done for reasons of compatibility with the `german` package (which uses the syntax `\selectlanguage{\german}`.)

Sifting through `biblatex.sty`, I found the following code snippet that patches internal `babel` commands. It may well reveal what needs to be done to properly expand `\thefield{hyphenation}` to "english" in my above example -- but to be honest, I have no clue what this code snippet does exactly.

```
\def\blx@mkbabel{%
  \patchcmd\bbl@set@language
    {\select@language}
    {\blx@langsetup\languagename\select@language}%
    {\ifdef\blx@thelangenv
       {\def\blx@beglang{%
          \blx@clearlang
      \begingroup
          \blx@imc@iffieldundef{hyphenation}
            {}
            {\blx@hook@initlang
         \def\blx@endlang{%
               \blx@hook@endlang
               \csname end\blx@thelangenv\endcsname
               \endgroup}%
             \csname\blx@thelangenv\expandafter\endcsname
               \expandafter{\abx@field@hyphenation}}}}
       {}%
     \blx@langsetup\bbl@main@language}
    {\blx@err@patch{'babel' package}%
     \blx@mknobabel}}
```

Long story, short question: How can I make my envisaged solution work, i.e. automatically switch languages for *citations* according to the bibentry's "hyphenation" field?

Comment: Interesting question. Might be reasonable to ask for an extension of any solution to csquotes' integrated interface (see section 5 of [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this works:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\blx@langsetup\abx@field@hyphenation%
\blx@hyphenreset%
}
\makeatother
```

In `\abx@field@hyphenation` is hyphenation value. Probably it needs some testing, if it is set.

---

edit:

Some time ago, I was looking at biblatex language switching because of problem with my citation style[1]. I didn't understand this code at all, so I ended with ugly hack[2].

But when I looked yesterday on biblatex's patch of babel you posted, I have found line

```
\blx@langsetup\languagename\select@language
```

Function `\blx@langsetup` uses `edef` to define `\blx@languagename`, which is used by macro `\blx@hyphenreset` to load hyphenation patterns, and then loads localization strings for given language. So in fact, instead of

```
\blx@langsetup\abx@field@hyphenation%
```

it is possible to use just

```
\edef\blx@languagename{\abx@field@hyphenation}%
```

Then there is problem with French language. When used as the main document language, instead of

```
... (Fis-
el 1985)...
```

there is

```
...(FISCHEL
1985)...
```

I think there is issue only with French, I tried Czech, Russian and Spanish and they worked correctly.

With `babel`, we can solve this issue with

```
\select@language\abx@field@hyphenation%
```

but, `polyglossia` in xelatex has same issue and this trick is there not working, I don't know how to fix that.

Anyway, if you don't need French with `polyglossia`, this is the current solution

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifcsdef{abx@field@hyphenation}{%
\edef\blx@languagename{\abx@field@hyphenation}%
\select@language\abx@field@hyphenation%
\blx@hyphenreset%
}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

[1] [Biblatex - using two languages in one reference entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/biblatex-using-two-languages-in-one-reference-entry)

[2] [Biblatex - using two languages in one reference entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/biblatex-using-two-languages-in-one-reference-entry/8820#8820)

Comment: Looks good -- I will do some further testing. Could you elaborate a bit how you came up with your code snippet?

Comment: @michal.h21: If I replace `ngerman` with `french` in my example and then add your code snippet, "Fischel" isn't hyphenated at all in the first and third paragraph. However, if I then add `\select@language\abx@field@hyphenation` to your code, things work as expected. It seems that one has also explicitely to switch to the new language to cancel the side effects of (e.g.) `french`. If you can confirm this modified solution, please edit your answer.

Comment: I will try to write some details tommorow

Comment: @lockstep I have edited my answer

Comment: @michal.h21: Please add the missing `\makeatother` in your second code snippet.

Comment: @michal.h21: The missing hyphenation of `french` actually seems to be a feature -- see section 28.1 of the babel documentation ("Family names should be typeset in small capitals and never be hyphenated"). I don't know why this is disabled with biblatex by default, but enabled with your first code snippet. While I'd like to have an explanation of this behaviour (and a tip how one could only switch hyphenation patterns for in-text citations), I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 6):

michal.h21's latest solution also works for the French language (at least if one doesn't use `polyglossia`), but its drawback is that it will also switch languages for terms like "ibidem", "sequens" and "sequentes". So I've adapted michal.h21's code to only switch hyphenation patterns:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsdef{abx@field@hyphenation}{%
    \edef\blx@languagename{\abx@field@hyphenation}%
    \blx@hyphenreset
  }{%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

A possible workaround for the French language is to use michal.h21's latest solution, but additionally to redefine the localization keys for "ibidem" & friends for every language used in a particular document so that they match the keys of the main document language.

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution sensitive to the `babel` option of `biblatex`. It wraps every citation in the `\blx@thelangenv` environment, which depends on this option. This should also work with `polyglossia`.

```
\gpreto\blx@hook@citekey{%
  \ifdef\abx@field@hyphenation
    {\ifdef\blx@thelangenv
      {\edef\blx@temp@langenv{\noexpand\csname\blx@thelangenv\endcsname%
          {\abx@field@hyphenation}}%
       \blx@temp@langenv}
      {}}%
    {}}
\apptocmd{\blx@citeprint}{%
  \ifdef\abx@field@hyphenation
    {\ifdef\blx@thelangenv
      {\csname end\blx@thelangenv\endcsname}
      {}}%
    {}%
}{}{\blx@err@patch{citeprint command}}%
```

**UPDATE:** This doesn't work with `biblatex` 2.8 and `polyglossia`. Instead the following patch can be used (BUT: see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146016/24176) answer by @PLK, `biblatex` is going to support the feature natively)

```
\patchcmd{\blx@citeprint}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\blx@beglang}
  {}{\blx@err@patch{citeprint command}}
\patchcmd{\blx@citeprint}{\endgroup}{\blx@endlang\endgroup}
  {}{\blx@err@patch{citeprint command}}
```

Comment: Did you try the 2.8a version with polyglossia?

Comment: I did some tests, everything is fine. Thanks for implementing this :)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @oleg prompting me, I have implemented this in the biblatex 2.8a development version available on SF. See the PDF doc for the `language` option. Basically, just set `language=auto` to turn on language switching for both bib entries and citations.