# Russian and Japanese and biblatex oh my

Tags: biblatex, xetex, languages, babel, cjk

I'm trying to typeset a book with bibliography entries in English, Russian and Japanese. Getting the bibliography to work right is driving me mad. I have got pretty close (I think) by cobbling together various answers from tex.se, but I'm still a little way away.

I think I have to use `biblatex` for this. `biblatex` doesn't support `polyglossia` so I have to use `babel`. No problem there. There is some support for Japanese in Babel as per http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/texwiki/?Babel

This is as far as I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[strict,autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[russian,japanese,english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=other,backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\newfontinstance\greekfont{Gentium Plus}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue=\hspace{0pt}}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\setromanfont{Gentium Plus}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bohan1928,
        Author = { ボハン, デ},
        Title = { 過去及び現在に於ける英国教会と正教会 },
        Journal = { 正教時報 },
        Volume = { 17 },
        Edition = { 9 },
        Year = { 1928 },
        Pages = { 5-9 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    Hyphenation = { japanese },
    Language = { japanese }
        }

@article{Dubrovin1906,
        Author = { Дубровин, А. И },
        Title = { Открытое письмо Председателя Главного Совета Союза Русского Народа А. И. Дубровина от 2 декабря 1906 года митрополиту Санкт-Петербургскому Антонию, Первенствующему члену Священного Синода },
        Journal = { Вече },
        Volume = {  },
        Edition = { 97 },
        Year = { 1906 },
        Month = { 7 дек. 1906 },
        Pages = { 1-3 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    Hyphenation = { russian },
    Language = { russian }
        }

@article{Brumbaugh1947,
        Author = { Brumbaugh, Thoburn T },
        Title = { The Protestant Handicap in Japan. },
        Journal = { Christian Century },
        Volume = 64,
        Edition = 23,
        Year = { 1947 },
        Month = { 4 June 1947 },
        Pages = { 708-709 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    Hyphenation = { english },
    Language = { english }
        }
                }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which outputs

```
References
Brumbaugh, Thoburn T (Apr. 1947). “The Protestant Handicap in Japan.” In: Christian Century 64, pp. 708–709.
Дубровин, А. И (июл. 1906). «Открытое письмо Председателя Главного Совета Союза Русского Народа А. И. Дубровина от 2 декабря 1906 года митрополиту Санкт-Петербургскому Антонию, Первенствующему члену Священного Си- нода». Русский. В: Вече, с. 1—3.
ボハン, デ (1928). ?過去及び現在に於ける英国教会と正教会? japanese. In: 正教時報 17, pp. 5– 9.
```

There is no support for Japanese in csquotes, so my quotes don't work. Also `biblatex` seems intent on putting the `language` tag into the body of the citation, which I don't want, and the auxilliary text ("In:", "pp.") in the Japanese entry is still in English.

Can I get any better than this?

Comment: With XeTeX, you don't need `babel` package at all. Use `polyglossia` package when necessary. And do not use `xltxtra`, `xunicode`, or `\CJKglue` yourself. It is rather complicated to configure `biblatex` to support Russian and Japanese properly, and the `language` entry is not designed for multilingual support.

Comment: AFAIK, `biblatex` does not directly support multilingual bibliography entries with different auxilliary texts in one document. You can choose one language while loading the package via `\usepackage[russian]{biblatex}` only.

Comment: The field to change the language is `hyphenation`, `language` specifies the language the work is written in (so could be ("latin and german") as well). While Russian is supported by both `csquotes` and `biblatex`, Japanese isn't at all, so you will have to do some defining on your own (see `csquotes.def` for `csquote`'s language definitions and `ruissian.lbx`/`english.lbx` for `biblatex`'s). The `biblatex` maintainers did some work on a multi script version of `biblatex`, that might be what you are looking for, but it is as of now unreleased.

Comment: @LeoLiu Bibliography entries can change the language with defined `hyphenation` fields and `babel=other` in the preamble. There seems to be a solution to change the citations as well [see here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21204/35864).

Comment: Summarising my long comment above: You can do better (the biggest problem is missing support for Japanese)! Use the `hyphenation` field and specify the language (in a format `biblatex` understands, see documentation). [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32933/35864) is a solution to suppress `language` fields. If you can spare the time write a localisation file for Japanese for `biblatex`.

Comment: For information, Joseph Wright has just contributed a change to the biblatex 2.8 DEV branch which seems to fix at least basic polyglossia support for bib string switching, just like babel.

Comment: Entirely wrong comment by @LeoLiu. Use `babel` with `xetex` as `babel-russian` is supported by native Russians in contrast to `gloss-russian` from `polyglossia` bundle. Use `biblatex-gost` with `biblatex` as it is also supported by native Russian librarian.

Answer (score 8):

I assume the OP has finished his book by now, but I found a solution and thought I'd share it anyway. With the `csquotes` package, a custom quote style can be declared with `\DeclareQuoteStyle`. The undesired "In: " can be removed from all citations using `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}`, and the page numbers can be omitted only for Japanese entries using the following:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\iffieldequalstr{langid}{japanese}
      {\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}} % if true
      {} % if false
}
```

The output and full code are below.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{russian}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKglue=\hspace{0pt}}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Minion Pro}

\usepackage[strict,autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{japanese}
  {「}
  {」}
  {『}
  {』}
\setquotestyle{japanese}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    language=auto,
    autolang=langname,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    ]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % removes "In:"
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\iffieldequalstr{langid}{japanese}
      {\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}} % if true
      {} % if false
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bohan1928,
        Author = { ボハン, デ},
        Title = { 過去及び現在に於ける英国教会と正教会 },
        Journal = { 正教時報 },
        Volume = { 17 },
        Edition = { 9 },
        Year = { 1928 },
        Pages = { 5-9 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    langid = { japanese },
%    Language = { japanese }
        }

@article{Dubrovin1906,
        Author = { Дубровин, А. И },
        Title = { Открытое письмо Председателя Главного Совета Союза Русского Народа А. И. Дубровина от 2 декабря 1906 года митрополиту Санкт-Петербургскому Антонию, Первенствующему члену Священного Синода },
        Journal = { Вече },
%        Volume = {  },
        Edition = { 97 },
        Year = { 1906 },
        Month = { 7 дек. 1906 },
        Pages = { 1-3 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    langid = { russian },
%    Language = { russian }
        }

@article{Brumbaugh1947,
        Author = { Brumbaugh, Thoburn T },
        Title = { The Protestant Handicap in Japan. },
        Journal = { Christian Century },
        Volume = 64,
        Edition = 23,
        Year = { 1947 },
        Month = { 4 June 1947 },
        Pages = { 708-709 },
        Keywords = {primary},
    langid = { english },
%    Language = { english }
        }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest, I ended up coding the bibliography by hand.