# German captions with BibTeX ("und" instead of "and")

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

If I quote a piece with two authors, I would like to have in the text: "(Spagna und Peattie, 2012)" instead of "(Spagna and Peattie, 2012)". If there are more than two authors, everything is fine again, since "et al." is written. I use the `apalike` bibliography style.

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\clearpage\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Referenzen}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{referenzen}
```

Here is an example of a piece with two authors; the citation call-out should use the conjunction "und":

```
@article{spagna2012terrestrial,
    title={Terrestrial locomotion in arachnids},
    author={Spagna, Joseph C and Peattie, Anne M},
    journal={Journal of Insect Physiology},
    volume={\textbf{58}},
    pages={599--605},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, the two variants looks identical to me. Also please make a small, but complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This should work. Please provide a fully working example. Does the error persist if you comment out `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: Does the posting [Bibtex link word "AND" with different translations in a single bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136067/bibtex-link-word-and-with-different-translations-in-a-single-bibliography) and the [associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142453/5001) solve your objective?

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you load `babel` with the option `german` rather than with the option `ngerman`? Does your document really adhere to the pre-1996 spelling rules?

Comment: I think this question has been erroneously been pointed out as a duplicate. The other question is about having different link words for different references. This question is as far as I understand only about getting "und" for a German document.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Biblatex instead, which takes care of that automatically.
Here is an example which uses the `natbib` option to make it more like natbib users are used to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referenzen.bib}

\begin{document}
Dies ist ein Beispiel \citep{spagna2012terrestrial}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Since Eli is using `apacite`, the `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` may be more suitable.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf The OP uses `apalike`, which is only "like APA" (`apacite` on the other hand would indeed give full-on APA 6th edition style). I would only use `style=apa,` if I really need APA style. For something "like APA" for some definition of "like", `style=authoryear,` is usually the better choice.