# biblatex/babel autolang= doesn't work with idemtracker

Tags: biblatex, babel

Although I was glad to discover that biblatex integrates with babel for bibliography formatting, I might have found a bug that prevents it to work with idem (not ibidem) entries.  Same goes with biblatex-dw (e.g. footnote-dw style), verbose*, historian and probably with any biblatex style.   I keep getting a space before punctuation in citations managed with the idem tracker although the collins* bib entries have langid = {english}.  Is there a workaround against this or should it be reported as a bug?  Thanks.

I think I am up do date with biblatex version 2.8.

Example with style=historian,

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@BOOK{collinscha,
  title={Changing Order: Replication and Induction in Scientific Practice},
  publisher={University of Chicago Press},
  year={1992 [1985]},
  author={Harry Collins},
  edition={New},
  langid={english}
}

@BOOK{collinsoth,
  title={another book title with same author},
  publisher={na},
  year={9999},
  author={Harry Collins},
  langid={english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english,ngerman,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=historian,backend=bibtex8,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{namedash={---------}}
\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{collinscha}.

\cite{collinsoth}.

Formating error: see how babel french made-up a space before the colon.

\cite{collinscha}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives,

[image]

Example with style=verbose-trad1,

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@BOOK{collinscha,
  title={Changing Order: Replication and Induction in Scientific Practice},
  publisher={University of Chicago Press},
  year={1992 [1985]},
  author={Harry Collins},
  edition={New},
  langid={english}
}

@BOOK{collinsoth,
  title={another book title with same author},
  publisher={na},
  year={9999},
  author={Harry Collins},
  langid={english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english,ngerman,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=bibtex8,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{collinscha}.

\cite{collinsoth}.

Formating error: see how babel french made-up a space before the colon.

\cite{collinscha}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives,

[image]

Comment: Hmm, the first thing to try is pulling biblatex 2.8 from Sourceforge again - there was a flurry of fixes just before the TL release for some spacing issue like this and I'm still not completely sure if they all made it into the version pulled into TL.

Comment: what is the question? It seems to me that the space bifore and afferma the colon is part of french typography.

Comment: In fact, yes - if you remove all of the biblatex commands from the MWE, you still get the space ...

Comment: Of course it's normal for babel french to add a space.  French is the default document language here.  However it shouldn't do that on langid={english} entries (works for the first citation, not the idem one).  That's the point.

Comment: @PLK, thank you for the information.  I overwrote the miktex 2.9 root dir content with the package I just downloaded from sourceforge (the 2.8 tds one) and launched a new TexWorks instance.  I hope that is fine.  But there is unfortunately no change in the result.

Comment: Actually, the strange thing is that you don't get a space on the first cite. There is no language switching support for citations yet (this is coming) and the language settings of citations are inherited from the current document language. So, the strange thing is why you *don't* get the space on the first cite.

Comment: I take that back, you are using verbose styles which use the bib driver for citations. Looking into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The issue is that verbose drivers use the bibliography drivers for the citations. The bibliography driver obeys the `langid` (given suitable `autolang` and `language` option settings). However, idem citations don't use the bibliography driver and so don't pick up the `langid` setting since normal, non-verbose citations can't yet be localised. You'd have to wrap the idem citation in a babel language environment to work around this.

Language switching for citations is implemented in an experimental biblatex branch - I tested it with your example and it fixes the issue. I will see about rolling this feature into biblatex for the 2.9 release.

Comment: Just to be sure: A feature similar (at least) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/biblatex-switching-languages-for-citations-according-to-the-bibentrys-hyphe will be implemented?

Comment: I fact it is exactly that feature. There will be `language=autocite` and `language=autobib` (the default) with `language=auto` setting both.

Comment: Please try the 2.8a biblatex in the DEV folder on SourceForge. Look at the new values for the `language` option in the PDF doc. Basically, just try with `language=auto`.

Comment: yes, it works now.  A temporary workaround for me would have been to \selectlanguage{english} before idem citations, but this is all fixed with 2.8a.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I wanted to mention - the 2.8a you downloaded was actually a mislabelled 3.0 experimental version. I have corrected this - you probably should get 2.8a again to make sure you have the right version.