# How to change editor bibstring in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, babel

I have text in Polish and I would like to change string "Wyed." with the string "Red.:"
Solution of the quite similar problem is here: [Changing predefined words in a biblatex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202192/changing-predefined-words-in-a-biblatex-bibliography). In my case it doesn't work. Also was not able to solve my problem by the use of the answers in topics [Adjusting biblatex bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152414/adjusting-biblatex-bibliography-style), [biblatex/babel autolang= doesn't work with idemtracker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145575/biblatex-babel-autolang-doesnt-work-with-idemtracker).

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}           % quotqtion signs customization
\DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}    % quotqtion signs customization
\usepackage[
    style=verbose-ibid,sortcites,
    maxcitenames=99 % maksimal number of auhtors listed in the bibliography item
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{% doesn't affect the pdf-file; why?
    editor = {red.:},
    editors = {red.:},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mylist.bib}
@inbook{gumplowicz2010,
    author =    {Gumplowicz, Ludwik},
    title = {O naturalnym prawie kształtowania się państw},
    booktitle = {Dwa życia Ludwika Gumplowicza. Wybór tekstów},
    editor =    {Mozetič, G. and Surman, J.},
    location =  {Warszawa},
    year =  {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mylist.bib}

\begin{document}
Aaaaa\footcite{gumplowicz2010}.
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `byeditor` string. The `editor` string seems to be *red.* already.

So use this:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
    byeditor = {red\adddot\addcolon},%
}
```

Though the `\addcolon` better belongs in the `byeditor+others` macro I think.

So I would do this:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{polish}{%
    byeditor = {red\adddot},%
}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+others}{\addspace}{\addcolon\addspace}{}{}
```