# References / bibliography - English and German literature

Tags: biblatex

I use German as well as English literature in my work (written in German). Switching between  "Vol."/ "Jg." and "No." /"Nr." in the bibliography works fine, but unfortunately there are some issues that I was not able to manage:

1. When I use \cite, \footcite and so on, the reference in my text / footnotes looks like this: e.g. "Beasley/Pagach/Warr (2008a, **p**. 10)" instead of "Beasley/Pagach/Warr (2008a, **S**. 10)"
2. Furthermore the date format in my English references is **mm/dd/yyyy**, but I prefer the **dd.mm.yyyy** format.
3. Last but not least there is something wrong with my line spacing in the bibliography. the spacing is sometimes too large - please have a look at the reference "Thommen/Achleitner (2012b)".

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,bibliography=totoc,toc=listof,chapterentrydots=on,captions=tableheading,headings=small]{scrbook}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
   \usepackage[ngerman,german,english]{babel}                                          
   \usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
   \usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}                                          
   \usepackage{microtype}                                                              
   \usepackage{ragged2e}
   \usepackage[format=hang,skip=2.5pt,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf]{caption}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{fp}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
   \usepackage[backend=biber,citetracker=true,autolang=other,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=true,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
   \AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


   % --- Backslash Authors --- %
   \newcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{} 
   \newcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\slash} 
   \newcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\slash} 
   \AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\revsdnamedelim\citerevsdnamedelim 
    \let\multinamedelim\citemultinamedelim% 
    \let\finalnamedelim\citefinalnamedelim% 
   } 

   % --- Semikolon --- % 
   \renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
   \renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 


   % --- () footnotes
   % --- () year footnotes
   \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

   \newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
     \iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {}
       {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
          \printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}

   \renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


   % --- authors footnotes / small caps text --- %
       \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

       \AtBeginBibliography{%
       \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textrm{#1}}}



   %%%%%%%%%% MODIFICATION: BIBLIOGRAPY %%%%%%%%%%

   % --- Sort authors --- % 
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

   % --- colon after author and year --- % 
       \renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

   % --- No "-" for the same authors --- % 
       \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false}        


   % --- more space between references --- % 
       \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 


   % - German vs. English literature - %
       \DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{
       \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Jg\adddot\addcomma}   %Jg. Zeitschr. 
       \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace Nr\adddot\addnbspace#1}          %Nr. Zeitschrift
       \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Aufl\adddot\addcomma}         %Auflage
       }

               \DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{
       \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol\adddot\addnbspace #1\addcomma}         %Vol. Journal
       \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace No\adddot\addnbspace#1}          %No. Journal
       \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Ed\adddot\addcomma}           %Edition
       }

       %\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{S\adddot\addnbthinspace#1}                          %"S." for all units

   % - title without quotation marks - %
       \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
       \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
       \DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}


   % - No publisher - %
       \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
       \printlist{location}%
       \iflistundef{publisher}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
       %  \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \usebibmacro{date}%
       \newunit}

   % - URL - %
       \urlstyle{same}

       \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext{Unter\addcolon}\space\url{#1}}      % "URL" --> "Unter:"
       \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}               % date without brackets

       \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%                                    % "besucht am" --> "am"
       urlseen = {am}}
       \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%                                   % "besucht am" --> "am"
       urlseen = {am}}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \bibliography{Master}
   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{Master.bib}

   @article{Beasley.2008,
    author = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and Warr, Richard},
    year = {2008},
    title = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
    pages = {311--332},
    pagination = {page},
    volume = {23},
    number = {55},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
    abstract = {},
    hyphenation = {english},
    note = {}
   }

   @article{Beasley.2008b,
    author = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and Warr, Richard},
    year = {2008},
    title = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
    pages = {311--332},
    pagination = {page},
    volume = {23},
    number = {55},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
    abstract = {},
    hyphenation = {german},
    note = {}
   }


   @incollection{Wilderom.2000,
    author = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
    title = {Organizational culture as a predictor of organizational performance},
    pages = {193--209},
    bookpagination = {page},
    publisher = {SAGE},
    isbn = {1412973651},
    editor = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
    booktitle = {Handbook of organizational culture {\&} climate},
    year = {2000},
    abstract = {},
    hyphenation = {english}
   }

   @incollection{Wilderom.2000b,
    author = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
    title = {Organizational culture as a predictor of organizational performance},
    pages = {193--209},
    bookpagination = {page},
    publisher = {SAGE},
    isbn = {1412973651},
    editor = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
    booktitle = {Handbook of organizational culture {\&} climate},
    year = {2000},
    abstract = {},
    hyphenation = {german}
   }

   @book{Thommen.2012,
    author = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Achleitner, Ann-Kristin},
    year = {2012},
    title = {Allgemeine Betriebswirtschaftslehre},
    edition = {7.},
    publisher = {{Gabler}},
    isbn = {9783834938442},
    subtitle = {Umfassende Einführung aus managementorientierter Sicht},
    hyphenation = {english},
    location = {Wiesbaden}
   }

   @book{Thommen.2012b,
    author = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Achleitner, Ann-Kristin},
    year = {2012},
    title = {Allgemeine Betriebswirtschaftslehre},
    edition = {7.},
    publisher = {{Gabler}},
    isbn = {9783834938442},
    subtitle = {Umfassende Einführung aus managementorientierter Sicht},
    hyphenation = {german},
    location = {Wiesbaden}
   }

   @misc{Ashby.2012,
    author = {Ashby, Simon and Palermo, Tommaso and Power, Michael},
    year = {2012},
    title = {Risk culture in financial organisations: An interim report},
    url = {www.lse.ac.uk/accounting/CARR/pdf/risk-culture-interim-report.pdf},
    urldate = {2016-08-22},
    abstract = {},
    location = {London},
    organization = {{The London School of Economics and Political Science - Centre for Analysis of Risk and Regulation}},
    hyphenation = {english}
   }

   @misc{Ashby.2012b,
    author = {Ashby, Simon and Palermo, Tommaso and Power, Michael},
    year = {2012},
    title = {Risk culture in financial organisations: An interim report},
    url = {www.lse.ac.uk/accounting/CARR/pdf/risk-culture-interim-report.pdf},
    urldate = {2016-08-22},
    abstract = {},
    location = {London},
    organization = {{The London School of Economics and Political Science - Centre for Analysis of Risk and Regulation}},
    hyphenation = {german}
   }

   \end{filecontents*}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   \begin{document}

   \noindent
   \textcites[][10]{Beasley.2008}[10]{Beasley.2008b}[11]{Wilderom.2000}[11]{Wilderom.2000b}[12]{Thommen.2012}[12]{Thommen.2012b}[13]{Ashby.2012}[13]{Ashby.2012b}
   \printbibliography

   \end{document}
   ```

---

I used the MWE for compiling the document (please find the screenshot attached below). Therefor I think there is an issue with one of the packages?! (I know this description is some kind of useless ...)
I`ll try to post a new MWE tomorrow ...

[image: No. and Nr. missing]

***NEW MWE:***

```
%%%% praeambel %%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,bibliography=totoc,toc=listof,chapterentrydots=on,captions=tableheading,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                         
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
\usepackage{microtype}              
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[format=hang,skip=2.5pt,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[language=autobib,backend=biber,citetracker=true,autolang=other,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=true,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\bibstring{and}\space}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{} 
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\multilistdelim} 



%%%% modifications %%%%
% --- indent footnotes ---%
\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{%
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

% --- backslash autors references --- %
\newcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{} 
\newcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\slash} 
\newcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\slash} 
\AtBeginDocument{%
 \let\revsdnamedelim\citerevsdnamedelim 
 \let\multinamedelim\citemultinamedelim% 
 \let\finalnamedelim\citefinalnamedelim% 
} 

% --- semikolon references --- % 
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 

% --- "u.a." --> "et al." --- %
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\,al\adddot}}                  


% --- round brackets --> cite / footcite
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


% --- authors small capital letters --- %
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textrm{#1}}}


%% ====== Bibliography ====== %%                            
% --- spacing references --- % 
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.25\baselineskip}                          

% --- sort name author --- % 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% --- ":" after author --- % 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}         

% --- title without quotation marks  --- % 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1}}                                   
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{{#1}}                              
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{{#1}}                          


% --- Englisch / German references --- %
%%% note: language --> hyphenation = {english} // hyphenation = {ngerman} %%%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Jg\adddot\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace Nr\adddot\addnbspace#1}% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Aufl\adddot\addcomma}%
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol\adddot\addnbspace #1\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace No\adddot\addnbspace#1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Ed\adddot\addcomma}% 
}


% - no publisher - %
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  %\printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

%%%% - URL - %%%%
\urlstyle{same}

%\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext{Unter\addcolon}\space\url{#1}}          % "URL" --> "Unter:"
%\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}               % date without brackets

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%                                      % "besucht am" --> "zuletzt besucht am"
    urlseen = {zuletzt besucht am}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%                                       % "besucht am" --> "zuletzt besucht am"
    urlseen = {zuletzt besucht am}}

% - chanching date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy -%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
    \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{\stripzeros{#1}\adddot}%
    \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
    \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
    \protected\def\mkbibneutord{\mkbibordinal}%
    \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
        {}
        {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
        \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
        \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
    \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
        \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
        {}
        {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
        \iffieldundef{#1}
             {}
            {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
            \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}




%%%% - bibliography - %%%%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@misc{BaselCommitteeonBankingSupervision.2015,
 author = {{BCBS}},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Title BCBS online document},
 url = {http://www.bis.org/filename.pdf},
 urldate = {2015-04-10},
 abstract = {},
 hyphenation = {ngerman},
 pagetotal = {55}
}

@misc{BaselCommitteeonBankingSupervision.2015e,
 author = {{BCBS}},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Title BCBS online document},
 url = {http://www.bis.org/filename.pdf},
 urldate = {2015-04-10},
 abstract = {},
 hyphenation = {english},
 pagetotal = {55}
}

@article{Sorensen.2002,
 author = {Sørensen, Jesper B. and Meier, Max X.},
 year = {2002},
 title = {Title Sørensen},
 keywords = {},
 pages = {70--91},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {47},
 journaltitle = {English Journal},
 shortjournal = {},
 hyphenation = {english},
 issue = {1}
}

@article{Sathe.1983,
 author = {Sathe, Vijay},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Title Sathe},
 keywords = {},
 pages = {4--23},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {12},
 issn = {00902616},
 journaltitle = {English Journal},
 hyphenation = {english},
 issue = {2}
}

@article{Schreyogg.1989,
 author = {Schreyögg, Georg},
 year = {1989},
 title = {Title Schreyögg},
 pages = {94--113},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {41},
 journaltitle = {German Journal},
 hyphenation = {ngerman},
 issue = {2},
 abstract = {}
}

@incollection{Wilderom.2000e,
 author        = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
 title         = {Title in edited volume - English},
 pages         = {193--209},
 publisher     = {SAGE},
 isbn          = {1412973651},
 editor        = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
 booktitle     = {Edited volume - Englisch},
 year          = {2000},
 hyphenation   = {english}
}

@incollection{Wilderom.2000,
 author        = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
 title         = {Titel Beitrag Sammelband - Deutsch},
 pages         = {193--209},
 publisher     = {SAGE},
 isbn          = {1412973651},
 editor        = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
 booktitle     = {Sammelband - Deutsch},
 year          = {2000},
 hyphenation   = {ngerman}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname}

%%%% text %%%%
\begin{document}

\textcite[][9]{BaselCommitteeonBankingSupervision.2015}

\textcite[][10]{BaselCommitteeonBankingSupervision.2015e}

Footnote I\footcite[Vgl.][11]{Schreyogg.1989}

Footnote II\footcites[Vgl.][12]{Sorensen.2002}[13]{Sathe.1983}

Footnote III\footcites[Vgl.][14]{Wilderom.2000}[15]{Wilderom.2000e}

Footnote IV\footcites[Vgl.][14]{Wilderom.2000}[15]{Wilderom.2000e}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [biblatex: Switching languages for *citations* according to the bibentry's “hyphenation” field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21204/2693).

Comment: `language=autobib,`

Comment: Do you want to switch the language of citations according to the `hyphenation`/`langid` field or just not? You will find that the setting `\usepackage[ngerman,german,english]{babel}` make English the main language of your document (the last language is the main language), so you will get English citations as they normally go with the main language (except stated otherwise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting

```
\usepackage[ngerman,german,english]{babel}
```

makes English the main language of your document (the last language is the main language), if you write in German, you want

```
\usepackage[german,english,ngerman]{babel}
```

(You could even drop `german` if you change all `hyphenation = {german}`s to `ngerman` - `german` is for pre-1996 orthography, `ngerman` is "neue Deutsche Rechtschreibung".)

Because the citations follow the main document language you get "p." instead of the German "S.".

---

The date format for English can be changed with

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{\stripzeros{#1}\adddot}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibneutord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
          \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

---

The extra space you are seeing is due to missing `%`s in `\DefineBibliographyExtras`, it should be

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Jg\adddot\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace Nr\adddot\addnbspace#1}% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Aufl\adddot\addcomma}%
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol\adddot\addnbspace #1\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace No\adddot\addnbspace#1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Ed\adddot\addcomma}% 
}
```

See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) for a bit of help on avoiding spurious whitespace.

This could probably better be done with proper use of the `bibstring` features, though I appreciate that the "Jg."/"Vol." thing is a bit complicated.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}                                          
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[language=autobib,backend=biber,citetracker=true,autolang=other,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,uniquename=false,uniquelist=true,isbn=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{} 
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space} 
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\multilistdelim} 


% --- () footnotes
% --- () year footnotes
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}



%%%%%%%%%% MODIFICATION: BIBLIOGRAPY %%%%%%%%%%

% --- Sort authors --- % 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% --- colon after author and year --- % 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

% --- No "-" for the same authors --- % 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false}        


% --- more space between references --- % 
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip} 


% - German vs. English literature - %
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Jg\adddot\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace Nr\adddot\addnbspace#1}% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Aufl\adddot\addcomma}%
}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol\adddot\addnbspace #1\addcomma}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addspace No\adddot\addnbspace#1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{#1\adddot\addnbspace Ed\adddot\addcomma}% 
}

% - title without quotation marks - 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}


% - No publisher - %
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

% - URL - %
\urlstyle{same}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\printtext{Unter\addcolon}\space\url{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}          

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%                               
  urlseen = {am}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%                        
  urlseen = {am}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Beasley.2008,
 author       = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and Warr, Richard},
 year         = {2008},
 title        = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
 pages        = {311--332},
 volume       = {23},
 number       = {55},
 journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
 hyphenation  = {english},
}

@article{Beasley.2008b,
 author       = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and Warr, Richard},
 year         = {2008},
 title        = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
 pages        = {311--332},
 volume       = {23},
 number       = {55},
 journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
 hyphenation  = {ngerman},
}


@incollection{Wilderom.2000,
 author        = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
 title         = {Organizational culture as a predictor of organizational performance},
 pages         = {193--209},
 publisher     = {SAGE},
 isbn          = {1412973651},
 editor        = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
 booktitle     = {Handbook of organizational culture {\&} climate},
 year          = {2000},
 hyphenation   = {english}
}

@incollection{Wilderom.2000b,
 author        = {Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Glunk, Ursula and Maslowski, Ralf},
 title         = {Organizational culture as a predictor of organizational performance},
 pages         = {193--209},
 publisher     = {SAGE},
 isbn          = {1412973651},
 editor        = {Ashkanasy, Neal M. and Wilderom, Celeste P. M. and Peterson, Mark F.},
 booktitle     = {Handbook of organizational culture {\&} climate},
 year          = {2000},
 hyphenation   = {ngerman}
}

@book{Thommen.2012,
 author      = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Achleitner, Ann-Kristin},
 year        = {2012},
 title       = {Allgemeine Betriebswirtschaftslehre},
 edition     = {7},
 publisher   = {{Gabler}},
 isbn        = {9783834938442},
 subtitle    = {Umfassende Einführung aus managementorientierter Sicht},
 hyphenation = {english},
 location    = {Wiesbaden}
}

@book{Thommen.2012b,
 author      = {Thommen, Jean-Paul and Achleitner, Ann-Kristin},
 year        = {2012},
 title       = {Allgemeine Betriebswirtschaftslehre},
 edition     = {7},
 publisher   = {{Gabler}},
 isbn        = {9783834938442},
 subtitle    = {Umfassende Einführung aus managementorientierter Sicht},
 hyphenation = {ngerman},
 location    = {Wiesbaden}
}

@misc{Ashby.2012,
 author       = {Ashby, Simon and Palermo, Tommaso and Power, Michael},
 year         = {2012},
 title        = {Risk culture in financial organisations: An interim report},
 url          = {http://www.lse.ac.uk/accounting/CARR/pdf/risk-culture-interim-report.pdf},
 urldate      = {2016-08-22},
 location     = {London},
 organization = {{The London School of Economics and Political Science -- Centre for Analysis of Risk and Regulation}},
 hyphenation  = {english}
}

@misc{Ashby.2012b,
 author       = {Ashby, Simon and Palermo, Tommaso and Power, Michael},
 year         = {2012},
 title        = {Risk culture in financial organisations: An interim report},
 url          = {http://www.lse.ac.uk/accounting/CARR/pdf/risk-culture-interim-report.pdf},
 urldate      = {2016-08-22},
 location     = {London},
 organization = {{The London School of Economics and Political Science -- Centre for Analysis of Risk and Regulation}},
 hyphenation  = {ngerman}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{\stripzeros{#1}\adddot}%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibneutord{\mkbibordinal}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkbibordinal{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
         {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
          \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textcites[][10]{Beasley.2008}[10]{Beasley.2008b}[11]{Wilderom.2000}[11]{Wilderom.2000b}[12]{Thommen.2012}[12]{Thommen.2012b}[13]{Ashby.2012}[13]{Ashby.2012b}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Please check the additional small changes I did to your code.

Comment: Thanks - it looks great. I think I will use the % more carefully ;)

Comment: Although the modifications work well in my MWE, there is a problem, when I run my document with all packages. There the German "Nr." and the English "No." are missing and the numbers are set in round brackets. Any idea, @moewe ? :S

Comment: @TRJW Sorry, no idea. Since the code works in the MWE, it must be something going on in your document. Try to come up with a new MWE that reproduces the problem and ask a new question for that. (But: does the format of the volume field look OK? Is only the number field affected? Are you talking about `@article` entry types, other other types?)

Comment: I´ve edited my first post - please have a look at the screenshot!

Comment: @TRJW As I said, it will probably take a bit more than just a screenshot, especially seeing that the code works fine in the MWE above. (I have but one guess: Did you by chance comment out the line about `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}`?)

Comment: No, i did not! :/ MWE follows today! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @TRJW Well that would have been too easy, I guess. We'll have to wait for the MWE then.

Comment: Here we go! I have to admit it is not a "Minimum"WE anymore! :S

Comment: @TRJW Ha, that was an easy one after all: Don't use the field `issue` for the journal subdivision below `volume`, the correct field is `number` (after all, you only modified the `number` field format). `issue` is for things like "Spring Issue"/"Special Issue about Dinosaurs", for numerical issues you need `number`. (Compare the `@article` entries in your first MWE - where it works - with the one in your second MWE - where it doesn't work.)

Comment: Now I feel a little bit embarrassed ... Thank you! I have modified my Citavi export and now it works.